# Plotting hours and Dates on chart using Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

Can anyone point me to an example for creating a plot chart using highcharts were the xAxis consists of the hours of the day 00:00 to 23:59 and the yAxis contains list of dates i can't find an example of how to achieve from the documentation.

basically the data that drives the chart would be something like this

15/05/2017: 09:00, 13:00, 14:30, 17:00, 19:15

16/05/2017: 09:30, 11:20, 12:45, 15:10, 18:00

17/05/2017: 08:30, 10:15, 13:00, 14:05, 20:30

Any examples or direction would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this example will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/0quce36h/ I have used heatmap with datetime type of xAxis

Comment: Sorry the example doesn't run so i cant see the output?

Comment: What problems do you have with my link? You are loading it as http or https?

Comment: The page loads fine, i can see the html and java script its just the chart is not there on the right. Tried running the example and chart didn't appear also?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Thanks not sure why but it seems to be working now. Heat map seems a good type of chart to use however theirs only ever going to be 2 states (on/off) so a scatter chart maybe better. How can achieve this an set the xAxis to display the hours instead of the days as per the dataset above?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/0quce36h/3/ If it will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer

Comment: The example is still a heat map if this can be achieved as a scatter chart then this this would definitely meet my requirements.

Comment: How you would like to display your scatter series? Do you want to have something similar to this chart? http://jsfiddle.net/0quce36h/4/

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for thanks :) the only addition would be plotting the points as HH:mm:ss but i assume to do that i would need to amend the date display format on the xAxis data?

Comment: Yes, you can use dateTimeLabelFormats in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/0quce36h/5/

Comment: I've been playing around with your example and i couldn't work out how to plot the times on the chart as 09:55:26, 10:28:32, 11:30:14 yet still display the xAxis along the bottom as hours (09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00)... Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tested this example? http://jsfiddle.net/0quce36h/5/ In this example you should see xAxis dates as HH:MM:SS

Comment: sorry I was inputting the times wrong, this is exactly what I’m looking for thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: Happy to read that my example worked for you :) I have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve chart similar to your requirements you can use datetime xAxis with scatter series.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

You can change your datetime label format to HH:MM:SS using  dateTimeLabelFormats parameter: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    millisecond: '%H:%M:%S',
    second: '%H:%M:%S',
    minute: '%H:%M:%S',
    hour: '%H:%M:%S',
    day: '%H:%M:%S',
    week: '%H:%M:%S',
    month: '%H:%M:%S',
    year: '%H:%M:%S'
  }
},
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/0quce36h/5/

Comment: In the example what is the val data used for (keys: ['x', 'y', 'val'],) i cant see it referenced on the chart anywhere? but thanks this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: The val is made just in case, because it is reference to the old heatmap chart i was suggesting you. you can use this val in your tooltip.formatter but you can also delete it and leave only x and y values

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function () {  
   var d = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:15:00");
   var n1 = d.getUTCMinutes();
   d = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:16:30");
   n2 = d.getUTCMinutes();
   d = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:19:33");
   n3 = d.getUTCMinutes();

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Time'
        },
        xAxis: {
            crosshair: true,
            categories: ['15/05/2017', '16/05/2017', '17/05/2017']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Military Time Hours'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: 
           [[n1], 
            [n2], 
            [n3]]
        }]
});
});
```

Comment: sorry i don't think this is correct  x and y axis data is the wrong way round. the chart needs to default to 00:00 through to 23:59 also.